# Do I need both WebVirtualDir Alias and WebApplication Name in wix?

Tags: wix

My understanding is if I want wix to install a web application, I need to specify a virtual directory, and then either embed a `<iis:WebApplication>` (as shown below) or reference one from the `WebApplication` attribute.

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="myVirtualDir" Alias="NameThatShowsUpInIIS" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" WebSite="myWebSite">
  <iis:WebApplication Id="myWebApp" Name="WhatIsThisFor" WebAppPool="myAppPool"/>
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```

In IIS this only shows up as a web application under the website, and there is only 1 name (that of the virtual directory specified in Wix). **What is the point of the mandatory `Name` attribute of WebApplication?**